# Ruby Sequel and array of patterns

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have an array of patterns for use with ILIKE, an existing dataset with other filters, and I want to add it to that.

```
patterns = ['abc%', 'bcd', '%cde', ...]
```

I use Postgres, so in SQL I would do something like `AND field ILIKE ANY('abc%', ...)`, but how to achieve that (or something similar, like dynamic `AND (field ILIKE 'abc' OR field ILIKE 'bcd')`? What would be the ideal solution with Sequel?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of the following should work

```
where(ary.map {|val| Sequel.ilike(:column_name, val)}.reduce(&:|))
#or
where(Sequel.lit("table_name.column_name ILIKE ANY(#{ary.map(&:inspect).join(',')})"))
```

Personally I would prefer the former but if you control the contents of `ary` then either should perform without issue.